# How do I assign a value to an optional instances property?

Tags: swift, option-type

This is a noob question but how come when I assign 'john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5' and then attempt to unwrap the value with optional-chaining, it prints "no rooms"??

I would think by assigning (numberOfRooms = 5) that it would contain that value???

```
class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms = 1
}

class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

let john = Person()
john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5      // I try to assign the value 5

if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
    print("\(roomCount)")              // why is roomCount not 5???
} else {
    print("no rooms")
}

// -> no rooms
```

Comment: Because `john.residence` is nil. Add `john.residence = Residence()` (or create an init for Person that sets recidense)

Comment: How is john.residence nil after I gave its property "numberOfRooms = 5" ??? I am really confused how this works...?

Comment: That is called optional chaining. It's saying, "if `john.residence` is not nil, then set its `numberOfRooms` to 5". But `john.residence` is still nil, so setting `numberOfRooms` to 5 has no effect.

Comment: You always need to instantiate a class or a struct before you can use it. `john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5` means, set the property `numberOfRooms` to 5 if `residence` is not nil otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5` will only assign to `numberOfRooms` if `john.residence` is non-nil. If it's `nil`, it won't do anything.

It's just syntactic sugar for optional binding, which lets you drill down long key paths of optional variables, like `a?.b?.c?.d` without needing to manually unwrap each object every step of the way. If anything along the path is `nil`, the whole expression just results in `nil`. If it's an assignment, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander stated and @Joakim Danielson stated, optional chaining is the reason for this. I would like to add a bit of information to this.

You need to instantiate at each step, i.e. treat each variable as their own variable.

Something more reasonable would be...

```
let john = Person() 
let johnsResidence = Residence()
john.residence = johnsResidence
john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5      // I try to assign the value 5

if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
    print("\(roomCount)")             
} else {
    print("no rooms")
}
```

1. We Assign `John` as a new `Person`
2. We assign John's `residence` as a new residence`
3. We assign John's Residence `numberOfRooms` to 5.

**IF we did not have a residence assigned, we cannot assign numberOfRooms.**

**IF we did not have a Person assigned, we cannot assigned a residence.**

Note: Try running this example as below:

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence
}
```

You will see that you will get a `nil` error when you try to do  `john.residence.numberOfRooms = 5`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your code piece by piece!

```
class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms = 1
}
```

That describes the Residence class. It has a `numberOfRooms` property which is initialized to 1 but can be changed later (`var`).

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}
```

That describes the Person class. It has a `residence` property which (read this carefully) is *initialized to `nil`*. It is an Optional whose default value is `nil`, and no actual Residence instance is being assigned initially. But it can be changed later (`var`).

```
let john = Person()
```

Now `john` is an actual *instance* of Person. As I just said, the `residence` property of that Person is `nil` by default.

```
john.residence?.numberOfRooms = 5
```

That says: "If `john`'s `residence` is not `nil`, assign `5` to its `numberOfRooms`; if it *is* `nil`, do nothing." And it *is* `nil`, so nothing happens.

What might you have done about all this? Well, at some stage of the story you might have given poor `john` a `residence`:

```
john.residence = Residence()
```

That never happened, so `john`'s `residence` is still `nil`.

I *think* your ultimate confusion is the meaning of this line:

```
var residence: Residence?
```

That gives `residence` a *type* (namely an Optional Residence) but not a Residence value; it is a `nil` Optional value initially, and will remain so until and unless someone assigns an actual Residence to this variable.